# GLibc optimizations required

Tags: gcc, glibc, libc

Why is it not possible recompile GLibc turning off all the optimizations (i.e., -O0)?

Particularly in doing this:

```
make CFLAGS='-O0 -w' CXXFLAGS='-O0 -w'
```

I get:

```
 #error "glibc cannot be compiled without optimization"
```

Comment: Find the repository, find the source of the message, find the commit which added it, and read the commit message?

Answer (score 8):

When I Google the error, the first result [tells](http://devpit.org/wiki/Gnu_Toolchain/Compatibility_Matrix#endnote_ODonell_and_Drepper_on_Inline) me exactly why.

> "In the early startup of the dynamic loader (`_dl_start`), before
>   relocation of the PLT, you cannot make function calls. You must inline
>   the functions you will use during early startup, or call compiler
>   builtins (`__builtin_*`).
>
> Without optimizations enabled GCC will not inline functions. The early
>   startup of the dynamic loader will make function calls via an
>   unrelocated PLT and crash." -- Carlos O'Donell

Comment: Why not just add the inline option (like -finline-functions and -finline-small-functions) and turn off the other optimizations? I tried but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @badnack: I don't know, I'm not the one who set this restriction... I'm just a messenger

Answer (score 3):

Basically:  "`glibc` is *voodoo!*"  This one "library of all libraries" has a *very* special place in any system, because virtually(?) *everything else* in the entire system relies upon it.

Therefore, if "someone out there" took the time to *prevent you* from compiling this library "without optimizations," I cordially invite you to take him/her at their word.  "There *must* be a [very good] reason."

Answer (score 0):

By Slackware operating system version 15.
In the folder:

```
/home/wsys0/glibc/glibc-2.36/build/
```

Create a file name cmp:

```
chmod 700 cmp
```

Put the following line into cmp:

```
export CFLAGS="-Wno-error -O3 -g"
../configure --prefix=/home/wsys0/glibc/out --disable-sanity-checks
```

Then run: `./cmp`, to install it.

Reference: https://sky-bro.github.io/posts/compile-and-use-your-own-glibc/