# bits/spin-lock.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, libc

I build glibc failed, and shows the message:

../libpthread/sysdeps/pthread/bits/mutex.h:34:30: fatal error: bits/spin-lock.h: No such file or directory

My system is ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
And I got the source with the command "apt-get source libc6-dev".
Build with the command:
../glibc-2.23/configure -CFLAGS='-g -O0 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fno-stack-protector' --with-headers=/usr/include

Why it failed, and is there any way to get the configuration information of the glibc installed in my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am on Ubuntu 17.04.

I *was* doing something very similar:

```
apt source libc6
cd glibc-2.24
dpkg-buildpackage # found in package dpkg-dev (which depends on a bunch of Perl scripts in libdpkg-perl)
```

This command should build an install-able package (but I wasn't patient enough to wait, since it iterates over several package configurations I don't think I need).

What I wanted to do was to reguild libc with debug information, using either:

- `dpkg-buildpackage` with `export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nostrip,noopt`, or
- `debuild` (found in package `devscripts`), see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/250437/how-to-pass-custom-options-to-configure-when-building-a-package-with-debuild).

... but that is another story.

The `dpkg-buildpackage` command emits logs, and within those logs, we find the configure command that is used (newlines for readability):

```
CC="x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-6 -no-pie -fno-PIE" \
CXX="x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-6 -no-pie -fno-PIE" \
MIG="x86_64-linux-gnu-mig" \
AUTOCONF=false \
MAKEINFO=: \
/usr/src/glibc-2.24/configure \
--host=x86_64-linux-gnu \
--build=$configure_build \
--prefix=/usr \
--enable-add-ons=libidn,"" \
--without-selinux \
--enable-stackguard-randomization \
--enable-obsolete-rpc \
--with-pkgversion="Ubuntu GLIBC 2.24-9ubuntu2" \
--with-bugurl="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bugs"    \
--with-headers=/usr/src/glibc-2.24/debian/include \
--enable-kernel=2.6.32 \
--with-selinux \
--enable-systemtap \
--enable-multi-arch
```

After some experimentation, I was able to reduce the number of essential flags required by the command, as follows:

```
# same as above
apt source libc6
cd glibc-2.24

# regenerate the configure script (not essential, but doesn't hurt)
touch configure.ac
autoconf

# extra setup (sets-up kernel and library headers for use with --with-headers)
make -f ./debian/rules

# cannot build in source tree anyways
mkdir -p build and cd build

MAKEINFO=: CFLAGS="-g -O2" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2" ../configure --prefix=/dbg --with-headers=/usr/src/glibc-2.24-git/debian/include --enable-add-ons=libidn

make -j 4

make install DESTDIR=$(pwd)/install  # testing installation
make check                           # 'actual' testing
```

Notes:

- the call to `make -f ./debian/rules` is **essential** to enable use of `--with-headers`
- apparently, **libc doesn't support debug builds** (non-optimized, that is): `glibc cannot be compiled without optimization` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089652/glibc-optimizations-required)). Even `-O1` is unsupported.
- `--enable-add-ons=libidn`: the default looks for 'add-ons' in all the sub-directories (equivalent to setting `--enable-add-ons=fbtl,libidn,libpthread`, with v2.24). If I add either `fbtl` or `libpthread` to the list, I get errors, i.e.:
  `No rule to make target '/usr/src/glibc-2.24-git/build/bits/stdio_lim.st', needed by '/usr/src/glibc-2.24-git/build/bits/stdio_lim.h'`
- In fact, libpthread gets built regardless of `--enable-add-ons`

Additional notes:

- I use `--prefix=/dbg` so that I won't install on top of the system libraries (and I am content to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to find my dependencies). You will have to set `--disable-sanity-checks` if you leave it to the default (/usr/local)
- `MAKEINFO=:` will avoid a small error later on (during `make install`)

Also, even if `make check` appears to work, some of the flags I removed might be important. I'm not an expert at building glibc.

Comment: Actually, the results of 'make check' are not perfect: 
Summary of test results:
    129 FAIL
   2348 PASS
     13 UNSUPPORTED
     43 XFAIL
      2 XPASS